# Lua getting started

Tags: lua

I just start learning Lua, and use [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/1.4.html) as tutorial

But now I have problem in chapter 1.4, when I type

`> lua -e "sin=math.sin" script a b`

then something go wrong

`lua: cannot open script: No such file or directory`

Can someone give me the idea about it? Thanks :)

P.S. I use Mac OSX 10.10.5 as environment, and Lua version is `Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio`

Comment: Is there a file called `script`?

Comment: Oh I get it! I misunderstood that script is a directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, thanks to Yu Hao.

`script` is a lua file, not a directive

I thinks it's better to understand:

`> lua -i -e "sin=math.sin" a.lua a b`